# the email could not be sent in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have issue with sending mail to users when they register and submit for reset password as well 
The error shows
**the email could not be sent. possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.**

Comment: DId you check with your hosting provider? It might be exactly what the error states or they may have special instructions for handling email from php

Answer (score 0):

Set SMTP settings in WP configuration, don't use mail() function.

[image]

And here you should configure your SMTP(gmail account for example):

[image]

More here: https://www.anphira.com/wordpress/fix-wordpress-mail/

Answer (score 0):

Its can be a server side issue, Im also having this problem on webmin virtualmin but the best way to fix if your mail server not working fine you can take a look on [postman smtp plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) its perfect and working good on all Wordpress sites.